# rails method chaining in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a search feature on top of some existing code that uses the Kaminari Gem to implement pagination. But that maybe isn't all that important. What I cannot figure out (as I am fairly new to rails/ruby) is method chaining. the following code throws this error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "courses" WHERE (name LIKE '%1%')

```
# GET /courses
# GET /courses.json
def index
  # @courses = Course.order(:title).page params[:page]
  if logged_in?(:site_admin)
    # @courses = Course.page(params[:page]).per(5)
    @courses = Course.search(params[:term]).page(params[:page]).per(5)
  else
    # @courses = Course.offered.page(params[:page]).per(5)
    @courses = Course.offered.search(params[:term]).page(params[:page]).per(5)
  end
end
```

the two lines that are commented out work without the addition of `search(params[:term])`

search method in the model:

```
def self.search(term)
if term
  where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%").order('id DESC')
else
  order('id DESC')
end
```

also, I am following the tutorial: https://rubyplus.com/articles/3381-Simple-Search-Form-in-Rails-5

Comment: are you using `includes` somewhere? if yes, you shouldn't. Check [this](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/issues/869#issuecomment-283411641)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a `name` inside `Course`. Either that or you forgot to run your migration?

To know if you have it on your database, look at your schema `db/schema.rb` and you should find something like this:

```
  create_table "courses" do |t|
    t.integer  "courses_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

take note of `t.string "name"`. If you don't have that, then you should generate a migration to create it.

`rails g migration add_name_to_courses name:string` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack), this is simple, optimise and will increase your search optimisation. you can modify it accordingly.